# Sketch the region

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

$ Re(z)+Im(z)= \frac{1}{Re(z)-Im(z)}$

Replace *Re(z)* with x and *Im(z)* with y to get:

$ x+y= \frac{1}{x-y}$

Then:
$ (x+y)(x-y)=1 $

$ x^2-y^2 =1 $

Assuming i did my math properly all i have to do is sketch the region of $x^2-y^2 =1 $ .
Help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have an equation for a hyperbola with branches starting at $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and branching out to $\pm \infty$ away from the starts.